# Training on MNIST, detecting sequences of numbers?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, mnist

After you've trained a model on the MNIST set, how can I now classify an image as having two digits? More generally, how do I train a model to detect any number of digits on an image?

Comment: You got already an answer with info on techniques. I wanted to add a side note to the discussion. You cannot do what you want (detect more digits in an image) while simply training on the MNIST dataset. You need to get a bit more creative, since the network architecture you may use will differ greatly from (for example) a RCNN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hot field called "object detection" that tries to do what you want. In general, you can detect anything (digits, people, cars, etc) from any images and even videos.

The state-of-the-art techniques roughly fall into two categories:

1. [Faster-RCNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497), which first proposes a lot of candidate windows for objects of your interest and then detects what are actually inside these windows.
2. [SSD](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325), which only scans the images once and detect objects, faster but not that reliable compared to Faster-RCNN.

A well-known real-time object detection method is YOLO (You Only Look Once), which falls in the SSD category, and has a very impressive real-time demo [here](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/), to give you a sense of object detection. Search these methods' names and you will find a lot of example code that satisfies your needs.

If you are only looking for digit detection, also check out work surrounding Stanford's [House Number Dataset](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/). However, note that these works are generally from five and more years ago and do not necessarily beat general methods like Faster-RCNN and SSD.